# How to Export attachments with parentType.field = 'ABC'?

Tags: soql, data-loader, attachment, dataloader.io

In my org i have a lot attachments available (55,000) and i need to export only those attachments which has `Account.field__c = 'ABC'` (10,000).

I am not sure this is possible in SOQL or not as i tried and it gives me an error, can anyone please tell me how to export those attachments only ?

What i have tried : `Select Body, Name, ParentId from Attachment where Parent.Type = 'Account' AND Account.field__c = 'ABC'`

I know above where clause is very typical but hopefully it might let you understand what exactly i need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery filter for this:

```
SELECT Body, Name, ParentId 
FROM Attachment
WHERE ParentId IN (SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Field__c = 'ABC')
```